# why have black something under photo?

Tags: html, css

```css
this is css the size of the photo is more than 400

*{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.sekil1{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: black;
}
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
this is html

<div class="sekil1">
  <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Sqbsu8piu7_D933-nUbqUmlCYx4HbRvP"> this is photo and the size of the photo is more than 400
</div>
```

the size of the photo is more than 400 *400. why have black something under photo?

https://codepen.io/cavad/pen/abBLNdv

Comment: remove the height from the div

Answer (score 1):

You have inserted the image into a div with a fixed size of 400px x 400px. You have assigned this div a black background color.
By setting instead max-width and max-height you told your image to keep its original aspect ratio. Thus being the image rectangular, only the width will take a value of 400px, leaving the remaining area of ​​the color of background of the div.

You could set the div's background color to transparent.

You could also do without setting the height of the div.

If your goal was to make the image square by cropping it slightly, then just replace max-width with width and max-height with height

I hope I was helpful!